# Prevent insert if condition is met

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, triggers, constraints

I have a table `Content` like this:

```
id | text | date | idUser → User | contentType
```

And another table `Answer`:

```
idAnswer → Content | idQuestion → Content | isAccepted
```

I want to ensure that the `Answer`'s date is bigger than the `Question`'s date. A question is a `Content` with `contentType` = 'QUESTION'.

I tried to solve this with the following trigger, but when I try to insert an `Answer` there's an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  record "new" has no field "idanswer"
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (SELECT "Content".date FROM "Content" WHERE "Content".id = NEW.idAnswer) < (SELECT "Content".date FROM "Content" WHERE "Content".id = NEW.idQuestion)"
> PL/pgSQL function "check_valid_date_answer" line 2 at IF
> ```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_valid_answer 
AFTER INSERT ON "Answer"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_valid_date_answer();
```

Trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_valid_date_answer() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$BEGIN
  IF (SELECT "Content".date FROM "Content"
      WHERE "Content".id = NEW.idAnswer)
   < (SELECT "Content".date FROM "Content"
      WHERE "Content".id = NEW.idQuestion) 
  THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'This Answer is an invalid date';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;$$;
```

So, my question is: do I really need to create a trigger for this? I saw that I can't use a `CHECK` in `Answer` because I need to compare with an attribute of another table. Is there any other (easier/better) way to do this? If not, why the error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Your `create function` has `if (select`.  The error message says `SELECT (SELECT `.  Are you sure the code in the question corresponds to the code that generated the error?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff That function was created in the `phpPgAdmin` graphic interface, but I copy-pasted that from the file exported from there.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your basic approach is sound. The trigger is a valid solution. It should work except for **3 problems**:

#### 1) Your **naming convention**:

We would need to see your exact table definition to be sure, but the evidence is there. The error message says: `has no field` **`"idanswer"`** - lower case. Doesn't say **`"idAnswer"`** - CaMeL case. If you create CaMeL case identifiers in Postgres, you are bound to double-quote them everywhere for the rest of their life.

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

#### 2) Abort violating insert

- Either raise an `EXCEPTION` instead of a friendly `NOTICE` to actually abort the whole transaction.
- Or `RETURN NULL` instead of `RETURN NEW` to just abort the inserted row silently without raising an exception and without rolling anything back.

I would do the first. This will probably fix the error at hand and work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trg_answer_insbef_check()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF (SELECT c.date FROM "Content" c WHERE c.id = NEW."idAnswer")
    < (SELECT c.date FROM "Content" c WHERE c.id = NEW."idQuestion") THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'This Answer is an invalid date';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The **proper solution** is to use [legal, lower case names](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) exclusively and avoid such problems altogether. That includes your unfortunate table names as well as the column name `date`, which is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in standard SQL and should not be used as identifier - even if Postgres allows it.

#### 3) Should be a [`BEFORE` trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER insbef_check
BEFORE INSERT ON "Answer"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_answer_insbef_check();
```

You want to abort invalid inserts before you do anything else.

Of course you will have to make sure that the timestamps table `Content` cannot be changed or you need more triggers to make sure your conditions are met.
The same goes for the fk columns in `Answer`.

Comment: Sorry, `idAnswer` is the correct column name, my bad. However, something isn't working correctly. I'm inserting an `Answer` with a date lower than the `Question` and the insert succeeds. 
PS: there's no `()` after the trigger name.

Comment: @HugoSousa: Ah yes, there is a third problem: you are not actually aborting the insert. Adding 3) to the answer ...

Comment: Just found the problem myself. Need to raise an `EXCEPTION`, not a `NOTICE`, it worked. Thanks a lot for the complete answer. Seems like I'm going to spend some time now changing my table and columns names :)
Also, just found this post answered by you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409952/trigger-vs-check-constraint. As a good practice, shouln't I be doing this with a `CHECK`constraint, as stated by @Str. ?

Comment: @HugoSousa: Exactly. Or `RETURN NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this in a different way.

Recommendation:

- use a BEFORE INSERT trigger if you want to change data before
  inserting it
- use a AFTER INSERT trigger if you have to do additional
  work
- use a CHECK clause if you have additional data consistency requirements.

So write a sql function that checks the condition that one date be earlier than the other, and add the check constraint. Yes, you can select from other tables in your function.

I wrote something similar (complex check) [in answer to this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791675/foreign-key-constraint-with-some-column-values-residing-in-other-tables/22023533#22023533).

Comment: So, you mean using a subquery on a `CHECK` constraint? I haven't thought about that but seems a good idea. Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000698/sub-queries-in-check-constraint

Comment: hmm, something like I wrote, see link. It is plain SQL.

Comment: and you would rather write CHECK... in your CREATE TABLE.

Comment: I'll give it a try and say something.