# PostgreSQL Update trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, triggers

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE annotations
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  annotation character varying(250),
  the_geom geometry,
  "rotationAngle" character varying(3) DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT annotations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = 4326)
)
```

And trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_angle
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON annotations
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE setangle();
```

And function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setAngle() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF    TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    UPDATE annotations SET "rotationAngle" = degrees( ST_Azimuth( ST_StartPoint(NEW.the_geom), ST_EndPoint(NEW.the_geom) ) )-90 WHERE gid = NEW.gid;
    RETURN NEW;
ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
    UPDATE annotations SET "rotationAngle" = degrees( ST_Azimuth( ST_StartPoint(NEW.the_geom), ST_EndPoint(NEW.the_geom) ) )-90 WHERE gid = NEW.gid;
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And when new row inserted in table or row edited i want to field `rotationAngle` setted with function result.
But when i inserting a new row in table function not work. I mean thath `rotationAngle` value not changed.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are triggering an endless loop. Simplify the trigger function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_angle()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW."rotationAngle" := degrees(
                             ST_Azimuth(
                                ST_StartPoint(NEW.the_geom)
                              , ST_EndPoint(NEW.the_geom)
                             )
                          ) - 90;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

- Assign to `NEW` directly. No `WHERE` in this case.
- You *must* double-quote illegal column names. Better not to use such names to begin with.
  [Recent related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143566/postgres-ts-vector/25144190#25144190)
- Code for insert & upgrade is the same. I folded into one code path.

Use a **`BEFORE`** trigger. This way you can edit columns of the triggering row directly *before* they are saved:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_angle
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON annotations
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_angle();
```

#### However

*If* you are just trying to persist a functionally dependent value in the table (and there are no other considerations): **Don't**. Use a view or a generated column instead:

- [Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268)

Then you don't need any of this.

Comment: Thanks, @Erwin you are wizard! Your answer awesome again, it's really nice that you giving not just a answer for the question but also an eplanation.

Comment: What should I do for partitioned table ? I can't create **BEFORE** trigger and my trigger didn't applied with **AFTER** trigger. I tested with both **NEW** and **OLD**. If I use `UPDATE` query with **AFTER** trigger , that may causes infinite loop.

Comment: I found the solution for my problem from one of your valueable answer from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137932/update-a-table-with-a-trigger-after-update)

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple things wrong here. 
1) When you insert a row 'A' the function `setAngle()` is called. But in the function you are calling another `update` within the function which will trigger the function again, and again, and so on...To fix this don't issue a update! Just update the NEW records value independently and return it.