# How do I update related object on update in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a one-to-one relationship between a Rule and a RuleStats object.  I am trying to modify the `last_updated` field on the RuleStats when any field on the Rule is updated.  If they were not two separate classes it would look something like this.

```
class Rule(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rules'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Base.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.stats = RuleStats(rule=self)

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False, default='')
    # ... more fields

    last_updated = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now, nullable=False)
```

But how do I do it if I have two separate objects,

```
class Rule(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rules'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Base.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.stats = RuleStats(rule=self)

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False, default='')
    # ... more fields

    stats = relationship('RuleStats', uselist=False, backref='rule', cascade='all, delete-orphan')

class RuleStats(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rule_stats'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Base.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    rule_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('rules.id'), primary_key=True)
    last_updated = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach would be

- Make function `Rule.update()` and do updates only through this specific function in your application. Example:

  ```
  from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import set_attribute

  class Rule:

     def update(self, **kwargs):
         """Update instance attributes and bump last_modified date in stats"""
         for key, value in kwargs.items():
                 set_attribute(self, key value)
         self.stats.last_updated = now()
  ```

Then:

```
 rule.update(description="Python rocks!")
```

If you want to make it transparent to the user, so that `RuleState` is always updated, even though you poke `Rule` attributes directly, you could use [Python properties](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) for this. This approach, however, leads more complex code base and I could not recommend it outhand.

Alternatively, you can use database triggers to execute the update on the database side. [Update trigger example for PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271883/postgresql-update-trigger).

There most likely exists an method doing this internally in advanced SQLAlchemy, but I don't have enough insight to tell where to start poking.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I thought of adding a setter function, but I would really like to do this automatically with SQLAlchemy.  That seems unlikely to be possible at this point without hooking into ```before_flush```, so I may have to fall back to this solution.