# After update trigger to replace an empty string with null updates all the data in that column to null

Tags: triggers, plpgsql, insert-update

I want to update the record of a particular user only. But the update trigger fires for all the users.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_empty_username_with_null() RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE user_temp
    SET username=null
    WHERE NEW.id = OLD.id and NEW.username = '';

    RETURN NEW;
END
CREATE TRIGGER replace_empty_username
    AFTER UPDATE OF username ON user_temp
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.username = '' AND OLD.id = NEW.id)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE replace_empty_username_with_null();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `NEW.id = OLD.id` makes sense in the `WHEN` clause of the trigger (*"ID did not change and is not null"*). But it makes no sense in the body of the trigger *function*, where it burns down to `TRUE`. Also, to only affect the row which is being updated, just use a `BEFORE` trigger instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_empty_username_with_null()
  RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.username = null;  -- !
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$

CREATE TRIGGER replace_empty_username
BEFORE UPDATE OF username ON user_temp -- !
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.username = '' AND OLD.id = NEW.id)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE replace_empty_username_with_null();
```

Related:

- [PostgreSQL Update trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271883/postgresql-update-trigger/25273309#25273309)