# trigger to silently preempt insertion in a table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

Is it possible for a trigger to be defined in such a way that the row that was to be inserted is not inserted, without raising an exception? My use case is that I want to simplify the exception handling for the  client library: the client library will just execute a statement to insert a row in a table and I was hoping that the trigger could be defined, more or less using the below syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER control_tr AFTER INSERT ON tableFoo
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE control_tr_fun();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION control_tr_fun() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (NOT condition_is_met(NEW.a, NEW.b, NEW.c)) THEN
        DO NOTHING INSTEAD OF INSERT // syntax I am hoping for instead of RAISE EXCEPTION
    ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I appreciate that I can ask the client library to call a PL/pgSQL function or make a trigger that `RAISE`s an exception and ask the client library to catch the exception (if raised) and just ignore it, but I am looking for a way to implement this as transparently for the client as possible.

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733254/prevent-insert-if-condition-is-met/22736148

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `RETURN NULL` then nothing will happen, the `INSERT` will fail silently. But you need to define the trigger as `BEFORE INSERT`, and **not** `AFTER INSERT` as it is in your example.

If you `RAISE EXCEPTION`, then the entire transaction will fail.

You can also `RAISE NOTICE` without failing the transaction and catch it in the client library, but only if it was the last notice produced. You cannot stack notices.