# Retrieve returning row of INSERT in PL/pgSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a table called `test` with the columns `id`, `data` in a PostgreSQL database.

I have created a trigger `AFTER INSERT` called `insert_test` that launches a function of the same name.

The insert SQL from PHP is this:

```
insert into test (data) values ('try') returning 'variables' as temp;
```

How can I access resulting values in `temp` inside the PL/pgSQL function?

Comment: You might even use a `BEFORE` trigger ([one example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22736148/939860)) to mess with the values *before* they are even stored and returned.

Answer (score 1):

This query is a bit ambiguous, so my reply will be generic. The result for the `RETURNING` clause is calculated dynamically and sent to the client immediately. So you cannot touch these values from PL/pgSQL. But all values from tables are available in trigger functions via record variables [`NEW` or `OLD`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html) - so you are able to recalculate any expression.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(a int, b int);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_trig()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '<<%>>', NEW.a + NEW.b;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_t AFTER INSERT ON foo
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo_trig();

postgres=# INSERT INTO foo VALUES(10,20) RETURNING a + b;
NOTICE:  <<30>>
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│       30 │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```