# PostgreSQL: CheckContraint with SubQuery?

Tags: postgresql

My PostgreSQL-table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Scheme"."TableName" (
    "ID"               serial4 NOT NULL,
    "ID-XyzPlist_fkey" int4    NOT NULL,
    "ID-Xyz_fkey"      int4    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "TableName_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"),
    CONSTRAINT "TableName_ID-XyzPlist_fkey_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("ID-XyzPlist_fkey") REFERENCES ...),
    CONSTRAINT "TableName_ID-Xyz_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("ID-Xyz_fkey") REFERENCES ...)
);
```

There are specimen "ID-Xyz_fkey" from a lab-production and we add pre-defined attributes "ID-XyzPlist_fkey". Normally, any "ID-Xyz_fkey" may have multiple entries "ID-XyzPlist_fkey", f. e.

```
ID-Xyz_fkey   ID-XyzPlist_fkey
123            5
456           18
789            2
```

There is on attribute 'Garbage'
"ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 35 f.e.

```
ID-Xyz_fkey   ID-XyzPlist_fkey
1000          35
```

and if there is an entry having "ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 35 that "ID-Xyz_fkey" must be blocked for any additional entry and that pair (1000 / 35) may only be added, if no entry having "ID-Xyz_fkey" = 1000 exists.

I tried a CheckContraint

```
ALTER TABLE "Scheme"."TableName"
ADD CONSTRAINT "TableName_ListNULL_check"
CHECK (( "ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 35) AND ("ID-Xyz_fkey" IN (SELECT "ID-Xyz_fkey" FROM "Scheme"."TableName" )));
```

and learned, that this is [not possible due to the SubQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13000698).

How to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Create a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) ?  ("_The trigger will be associated with the specified table, view, or foreign table and will execute the specified function function_name when certain operations are performed on that table._")

Comment: Thanks! I'm using triggers to set a DateCreated or DateModified. But how to use triggers to block a data entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading your criteria: the [partial unique index or an exclusion constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77039511/5298879) can't affect any records that don't satisfy their predicate, leaving only the [`trigger`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) or a [`rule`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html). [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/W56szZ-c):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_trigger_xyzplist_garbage_exclusions() 
RETURNS trigger language plpgsql AS $f$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM "Scheme"."TableName" AS another
              WHERE new."ID-Xyz_fkey"=another."ID-Xyz_fkey"
              AND 35 in (another."ID-XyzPlist_fkey", new."ID-XyzPlist_fkey") )
   THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Conflicting "ID-Xyz_fkey"=% present',new."ID-Xyz_fkey";
   END IF;
   RETURN new;
END $f$;

CREATE TRIGGER f_trigger_xyzplist_garbage_exclusions
BEFORE INSERT ON "Scheme"."TableName"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_trigger_xyzplist_garbage_exclusions();
```

A [rule](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules.html), while shorter and potentially faster, also works a bit differently: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SG3ClCFY)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE garbage_exclusion_on_tablename AS ON INSERT TO "Scheme"."TableName"
WHERE (EXISTS ( SELECT FROM "Scheme"."TableName" AS t 
                WHERE t."ID-Xyz_fkey" = new."ID-Xyz_fkey" 
                AND  35 IN (t."ID-XyzPlist_fkey", new."ID-XyzPlist_fkey") ) )
DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

Notice that it doesn't raise an exception and instead does nothing. You could `INSTEAD SELECT` a [function](https://dbfiddle.uk/VXUkwoA7) that raises the exception, but it's still breaking other things, like `insert...returning` targeting that table.

Comment: Thank you @Zegarek, definately we need a message on exceution, so I prefer the FUNCTION / TRIGGER. Looking at you FUNCTION (not sure if I oversee it completely), I'm not sure that it covers both cases:  
CASE 1: A record exists with "ID-Xyz_fkey" = 999 and "ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 4, a new record for   "ID-Xyz_fkey" = 999 and "ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 35 must be blocked.  
CASE 2: A record exists with "ID-Xyz_fkey" = 999 and "ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 35, a new record for   "ID-Xyz_fkey" = 999 and "ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 1 must be blocked.  
Does your code cover both cases?

Comment: @StOMicha Yes, both are covered and demonstrated on db<>fiddle (under "demo" links).

Comment: Thank you @Zegarek, checking the code for the function above and in the demo there are differences, also different number of lines Will it be OK to use the code from the fiddle?

Comment: The trigger function in the first one has a longer exception message with additional case giving more detail about the conflict, but the logic leading to the exception remains unchanged. The rule in the second one is the same.

Comment: Thank you so much @Zegarek, I used the Code from the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W56szZ-c) and added for the trigger: BEFORE INSERT **_OR UPDATE_** ON. For my understanding, I changed »another« three times  to »rec_exist«, that worked. Now I want to change »new« five times (not in the text) to »rec_edit« but this throws an ERROR: Missing entry in FROM-Clause for  »rec_edit«. Any idea about that?

Comment: `AS another` is a regular alias for a table referenced by the `SELECT` statement, so you can rename it according to your preference. However, `NEW` (or `new`, or `nEw` - it's case-insensitive) is a [special trigger function variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) that lets you reference the incoming record, you can't rename it. Since you only read from it, you *could* reassign its value: `declare rec_edit record:=new;` before `begin`. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QVuhCxXd).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zegarek for the perfect solution and the detailed explanations; I've learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This initially sounded like a job for a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3). All your specimens and attributes can be combined freely, except for records with attribute `35` - the db will make sure each of those has a unique specimen: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5WRA4ePu)

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX partial_unique_plist_for_fkey35 
ON "Scheme"."TableName" ("ID-Xyz_fkey")
WHERE ("ID-XyzPlist_fkey"=35);
```

Same could be done with an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION):

```sql
ALTER TABLE "Scheme"."TableName" 
ADD CONSTRAINT exclude_non_unique_plist_for_fkey35
EXCLUDE ("ID-Xyz_fkey" WITH =) WHERE ("ID-XyzPlist_fkey"=35);
```

[But](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE):

> If all of the specified operators test for equality, this is equivalent to a UNIQUE constraint, although an ordinary unique constraint will be faster.

A [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE) can also do the job but is even slower, bulkier and less maintainable than either of the above.

---

Problem is, neither of the above cares about any record that *isn't* marked as garbage with `"ID-XyzPlist_fkey"=35`. While they can both guard against duplicate `"ID-Xyz_fkey"` with `"ID-XyzPlist_fkey"=35`, a pre-existing non-garbage pair `(1000,34)` doesn't stop `(1000,35)` from being inserted. Similarly, the presence of a `(999,35)` garbage pair in the table won't stop `(999,34)` from getting accepted.

Comment: Thank you @Zegarek, I started with the second proposal "... ADD CONSTRAINT..."; and don't understand the syntax   
[EXCLUDE ("ID-XyzPlist_fkey" WITH =) WHERE ("ID-Xyz_fkey"=35);]  

Did you mix up the variables? A specimen "ID-Xyz_fkey" is marked as 'Garbage' with  
"ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 35  
and this should not allow any other entry for that "ID-Xyz_fkey".

Comment: @StOMicha It's likely that I did mix them up :) I'll edit the answer and the demo in the moment, but the point stands. Note that while exclusion constraint is more flexible in terms of control over the exclusion logic, in your case a partial unique is more suitable - as per the quote from the doc

Comment: @StOMicha I re-read the example from your question and it turns out I did set it up in reverse. I've now edited the answer and the demo, swapping those back around.

Comment: Thank you! I did it as you described [... ADD CONSTRAINT ...] this runs well. But having this and record "ID" = 7604  with "ID-Xyz_fkey" = 6123, "ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 4, I can add for "ID-Xyz_fkey" = 6123 record "ID" = 7604, "ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 35 and after that "ID" = 7605, "ID-XyzPlist_fkey" = 1. So for both cases it's not working with PosgreSQL 15.3.5. Any Idea?

Answer (score -1):

I do not have much experience in creating triggers, but this seems to work:

(with some help from: [Prevent insert if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733254/prevent-insert-if-condition-is-met)

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trg_check()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF exists (SELECT 1 FROM "TableName"  WHERE "ID-XyzPlist_fkey"=35 and "ID-Xyz_fkey"=1000)
   THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'fkey 35/1000 does exist';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_check
BEFORE INSERT ON "TableName"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_check();
```

And the test:

```
luuk=# insert into "TableName"("ID-XyzPlist_fkey","ID-Xyz_fkey") values (35,1000);
INSERT 0 1
luuk=# insert into "TableName"("ID-XyzPlist_fkey","ID-Xyz_fkey") values (36,1000);
ERROR:  fkey 35/1000 does exist
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function trg_check() line 5 at RAISE
luuk=# delete from "TableName" where "ID-XyzPlist_fkey"=35;
DELETE 1
luuk=# delete from "TableName" where "ID-XyzPlist_fkey"=36;
DELETE 0
luuk=# insert into "TableName"("ID-XyzPlist_fkey","ID-Xyz_fkey") values (36,1000);
INSERT 0 1
luuk=#
```